# Contravariance troubles with nested interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, generics, contravariance, nested-generics

```
interface IModel
{ 
}

class ModelA : IModel
{
}

interface IService<T> where T: IModel
{
}

class ServiceA : IService<ModelA>
{
}
```

Given the definition of classes and interfaces above, 
The following works:

```
IModel model = new ModelA();
```

Indicating that `ModelA` can be cast to its interface `IModel`

The following also works:

```
IService<ModelA> service1 = new ServiceA();
```

Indicating that `ServiceA` can be cast to its interface `IService<ModelA>`

However, the following fails:

```
IService<IModel> service2 = new ServiceA();
```

The error message says that `ServiceA` cannot be implicitly to converted to `IService<IModel>`

Im surprised by this since:
`ModelA` can be cast to `IModel`, and
`ServiceA` can be cast to `IService<IModel>`
i was expecting the following to happen:
`ServiceA` -> `IService<ModelA>` -> `IService<IModel>`

But that doesnt seem to be possible.

Anyone have an explanation to why that is?

Comment: Consider that `IService<T>` has method `void Foo(T x)`. If you could convert `IService<ModelA>` to `IService<object>`, then you can now call `Foo` with any object. That can't work.

Comment: @CharlesMager Makes sense! Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only real option you have here is to apply the `out` modifier on the generic type of `IService` making it *Covariant*

> Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than that specified by the generic parameter

```
interface IService<out T> where T : IModel
{
}
```

[out (generic modifier) (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

---

To be specific, as much as it seems like it `IService<IModel>` is not the same thing as `ServiceA : IService<ModelA>`

`out` means (roughly speaking), it can only appears in output positions.

*Be warned though, this will seriously limit what you can do with `T`.*

If you need to use `T` in `IService` (and it's not just a return of method in `IService`) , then you may need to use `object` or rethink the problem.